# Extracting time of a work of a process in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, process

Is there any commands/parameters, which allow me to know for how long the process has been working? I tried to search something in commands *ps* and *top* , but didn't find it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a process whose time you want to (or accept to) collect after it ends, simply use the `time` command. It's available as an independent command and usually as a shell builtin as well.

```
$ time sleep 5
real    0m5.028s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

For a process that's still running, have a look at `ps`'s formatting options.

```
$ ps -o time,etime 1
```

Exact option name might vary with the system, be sure to check your `ps` manual.